# Simple Captcha Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am trying to use the simple-captcha gem with

```
gem "galetahub-simple_captcha", :require => "simple_captcha".
```

I am running Rails 5.0.0.1 and Ruby 2.3.2.

I couldn't get it to work in my app so I created a clean skin, `rails new`, `rails generate scaffold User`, `rake db:migrate` etc.  As soon as I add the gem, I can `bundle install` fine, but as soon as I run `rails test` or `rails generate` or anything I get this error:

```
user/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.3/gems/galetahub-simple_captcha-0.1.5/lib/simple_captcha/form_builder.rb:7:in `included': uninitialized constant Sprockets::Helpers (NameError)
```

I have tried following the setup instructions for the gem, which says to run `rails generate captcha` after installing the gem, but as soon as I have installed the gem I get the error.

Any help would be appreciated.

On the other hand if anyone thinks there is a better captcha I should be using for form submission, let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like latest commit to "simple_captcha" repository was 3 years ago. It's outdated and maybe it will be not worked with Rails 5.

You can use Recaptcha from Google https://github.com/ambethia/recaptcha

Answer (score 0):

You can use Recaptcha gem as advised by Alex

There is nice tutorial for this https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-add-recaptcha-to-your-rails-application/

Comment: Thanks got Recaptcha working fine.  Will keep my eye out for the age of these repositories in the future.

Answer (score 0):

What happens after the simple captcha is installed?